# Evento onclick em duas paginas diferentes

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos, onclick

Estou praticando em JS e resolvi criar um programinha... um *churrascômetro*.

A questão é a seguinte, criei duas páginas, sendo uma a `index.html` e a segunda para que quando o usuário clique no botão `calcular`, ele seja redirecionado pra lá, e que os valores carreguem nesta segunda página em forma de lista.

Apontei as duas páginas para o mesmo arquivo JavaScript. O problema é que não sei o que estou fazendo de errado, pois quando quando clico no botão, eu sou redirecionado para a segunda tela, mas não carrega os valores como eu queria.

Será que podem me ajudar apontando o que estou fazendo de errado?

**Documento index.html:**

```
<center class="container">
    <div class="card border-dark mb-3 my-5" style="max-width: 30rem;">
        <div class="card-header"><h3>Churrascômetro</h3></div>
        <div class="card-body text-dark">
            <form action="lista.html">
                <input type="number" id="adultos" class="form-control my-3 col-8" placeholder="Adultos">
                <input type="number" id="criancas" class="form-control my-3 col-8" placeholder="Crianças">
                <input type="number" id="duracao" class="form-control my-3 col-8" placeholder="Duração">
                <button type="submit" id="btnCalc"class="my-5 col-8 btn btn-outline-dark btn-lgbtn-block">Calcular</button>
                <div></div>
            </form>    

        </div>
    </div>
</center>
```

**HTML da segunda página:**

```
center class="container">
    <div class="card border-dark mb-3 my-5" style="max-width: 30rem;">
        <div class="card-header"><h3>Lista de compras</h3></div>
        <div class="card-body text-dark">
            <a href="index.html" role="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-block col-4">Novo Churrasco</a>
            <div id="lista"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</center>
```

**Código JavaScript:**

```
var adultos = document.querySelector("#adultos")
var criancas = document.querySelector("#criancas")
var duracao = document.querySelector("#duracao")
var btnCalc = document.querySelector("#btnCalc")
var lista = document.querySelector("#lista")

btnCalc.onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault
    lista.innerHTML = "teste"
}
```

Comment: onde na sua página você tá redirecionando pra outra?

Comment: Explique umas coisas que não estão claras: Onde está `HTML da segunda página:` seria a página `lista.html`? Esse código solto em javascript pertence a qual página? Sua intenção é passar os valores dos campos de formulário na página `index.html` para o elemento `<div id="lista"></div>` do html onde está escrito `HTML da segunda página:`?

Comment: Vc pode passar os dados de uma página a outra colocando `name` nos campos do formulário, e não `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Em minha opinião uma solução seria a utilização de [Cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) ou do [WebStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Você podeira por exemplo:

**HTML primeira página**

```
<center class="container">
    <div class="card border-dark mb-3 my-5" style="max-width: 30rem;">
        <div class="card-header"><h3>Churrascômetro</h3></div>
        <div class="card-body text-dark">
           <input type="number" id="adultos" class="form-control my-3 col-8" placeholder="Adultos">
           <input type="number" id="criancas" class="form-control my-3 col-8" placeholder="Crianças">
           <input type="number" id="duracao" class="form-control my-3 col-8" placeholder="Duração">
           <button type="button" id="btnCalc"class="my-5 col-8 btn btn-outline-dark btn-lgbtn-block">Calcular</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</center>
```

**JavaScript primeira página**

```
var btnCalc = document.querySelector("#btnCalc");

btnCalc.onclick = function(e){
    var adultos = document.getElementById("#adultos").value;
    var criancas = document.getElementById("#criancas").value;
    var duracao = document.getElementById("#duracao").value;

    localStorage.setItem("adultos", adultos);
    localStorage.setItem("criancas", criancas);
    localStorage.setItem("duracao", duracao);

     window.location.href="segundapagina.html";
}
```

**HTML segunda página**

```
center class="container">
    <div class="card border-dark mb-3 my-5" style="max-width: 30rem;">
        <div class="card-header"><h3>Lista de compras</h3></div>
        <div class="card-body text-dark">
            <a href="index.html" role="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-block col-4">Novo Churrasco</a>
            <div id="lista"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</center>
```

**JavaScript segunda página**

```
window.onload = function(){
    var lista = document.querySelector("#lista");
    var adultos = localStorage.getItem("adultos");
    var criancas = localStorage.getItem("criancas");
    var duracao = localStorage.getItem("duracao");

    //resto da função
}
```

São dois arquivos JS separados.

Answer (score -1):

O html por si só quando você muda de pagina por link é carregado tudo novamente, nada fica salvo. Se você quer que algo seja mantido e funcionando no browser sem ter um servidor backend você pode utilizar o cache do browser ou um indexdb. Mas sinceramente usando forms sem ter um backend não faz muito sentido.

Link de referencia para cache: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Cache
Link de referencia para indexdb : https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Usando_IndexedDB